# C segmentation fault when I try to printf just after printing the first value inside function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am getting *segmentation fault* when I try to use `printf` on `*buffer[i]` in `readWav()` function. And `buffer` was able to correctly pass to `main()` and I was able to check values in `main` with `datas[i]`. I simply copied the `printf` in `main()` and had to replace `datas[i]` with `*buffer[i]` then it compiles fine. It prints the first value in `readWav()` and then *SegFault* occurs.

How do I do this in `readWav()` - What is wrong with `*buffer[i])` - in other words, if `datas[i]` refers to actual values in `main()` what would that be in `readWav()` in terms of `buffer`?

Update:
`main()` will pass `datas` to other functions still to be added on. That is why I tried printing it in `readWav()` thinking it will be very similar in how values are passed on to other functions - please correct me if I am wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sndfile.h"

int readWav(const char *const fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int   sRates, sRatem, ret;
    long  nSamples = 0, nSamplem;
    float *datas, *datam;

    printf("Read Test\n");
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expecting two wav file as argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    ret = readWav(argv[1], &nSamples, &sRates, &datas);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        nSamples, argv[1], sRates, (float)nSamples/sRates);

    for (i=0; i < nSamples ; i++) {
        printf("%d\t %f\n", i, datas[i]);
    }

    free(datas);

    return 0;
//Cleanup etc:
}

int readWav(const char *const fname, long *numFrames, int *sRate, float **buffer)
{
    // Open sound file
    SF_INFO sndInfo;

    if ((sRate == NULL) || (numFrames == NULL) || (buffer == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid arguments passed to readWav()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    SNDFILE *sndFile = sf_open(fname, SFM_READ, &sndInfo);
    if (sndFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading source file '%s': %s\n", fname, sf_strerror(sndFile));
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate memory
    *buffer = malloc(sndInfo.frames * sndInfo.channels * sizeof(float));
    if (*buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for file\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);

        return 1;
    }

    *sRate = sndInfo.samplerate;
    // Load data
    *numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, *buffer, sndInfo.frames);
    // Check correct number of samples loaded
    if (*numFrames != sndInfo.frames) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not read enough frames for source\n");
        sf_close(sndFile);
        free(*buffer);
    }
    else {
        printf("Successfully read file\n");
        *numFrames = sndInfo.frames;
    }
    // Output Info
    printf("Read %ld frames from %s, Sample rate: %d, Length: %fs\n",
        *numFrames, fname, *sRate, (float)*numFrames/sndInfo.samplerate);

    for (i=0; i < sndInfo.frames ; i++) {
        printf("%d\t %f\n", i, *buffer[i]);
    }

    sf_close(sndFile);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You have to dereference first: `(*buffer)[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an array index **BEFORE** derefencing the pointer.

You meant to do `(*buffer)[i]`, but did `*(buffer[i])` instead *(notice how I added the parenthesis for clarity)*.

Next time, remember that `*` has a lower precedence than `[]`.

Comment: Thanks it works. If I add a third function, say fthird(), then I can follow the same format as with readWav()?

Comment: I'd imagine. I only skimmed your code, but knew immediately because I had a similiar problem before. Don't forget you can accept answers you think answer the question the best!

Comment: Awesome Isaiah - your explanation of precedence {* has a lower precedence than [] }